# Find all $(x,y)\in\mathbb Z$ s.t. $x^2(x^2+1)=21^y-1$

Tags: number-theory, functions

> $Q.$ Find all $(x,y)\in\mathbb Z^2$ s.t. $$x^2(x^2+1)=21^y-1$$

I tried to simplify it, $$x^4+x^2+(1-21^y)=0$$
It's just a quadratic equation , so I solved for $x^2$ $$x^2=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-4(1-21^y)}}{2}$$

as $x^2\in\mathbb Z^+$ , $\Delta=a^2$ where  $a\in\mathbb Z^+$

So $$1-4(1-21^y)=a^2\implies\underbrace{4(21^y-1)}_{\mathbb E^+}=(a+1)(a-1)\tag1$$

Which means either $(a+1)\in\mathbb E^+$ or $(a-1)\in\mathbb E^+$ , but this doesn't matter as both $(a+1),(a-1)\in\mathbb E^+$ . This is because *difference of two consecutive Even number is $2$* .

So let $(a-1)=2p$ , then $(a+1)=2(p+1)$ . Using this value in $eq^n(1)$ $$4(21^y-1)=4p(p+1)\implies\underbrace{4\cdot21^y-3}_{\Delta}=(2p+1)^2$$

Hence $a\in\mathbb O^+$

Now $$x^2=\begin{cases}\frac{-1+(2p+1)}{2}=p\\\frac{-1-(2p+1)}{2}=-(p+1)\end{cases}$$

But I'm not able to solve it further, any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean finding integer solutions?

Comment: I know two solutions i.e. $(0,0)$ and $(2,1)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only solutions are $(0,0)$, $(2,1)$, and $(-2,1)$.

- It's easy to check that these are the only solutions with $y\in\{0,1\}$.
- There are no solutions with $y<0$ since the left-hand side is an integer.
- Finally, when $y\ge2$, the right-hand side is congruent to $8$ (mod $9$); however, one can check that the left-hand side can be congruent only to $0$ or $2$ (mod $9$).